# can not read property of &#39;id&#39 of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to update a course using postman but there seems to be something wrong
Can anyone help me solve the problem?

```
const courses = [
    {id: 1, name: "course1"},
    {id: 2, name: "course2"},
    {id: 3, name: "course3"}
]
sending the request 
app.put('/api/courses/:id', (res, req) => {
    //look up the Course.
    let course = courses.find(c => c.id == parseInt(req.params.id))
    if(!course) res.status(404).send('404 Course Not Found to Up Date')

    //validate the Course.
    const { error } = validateCourse(req.body)
    if(error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
        return
    }
     //Up Date The Course.
    course.name = req.body.name
    res.send(course)
})
```

Comment: Do you have the backtrace of that error pointing to some line number?

Comment: most likely `req.params` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You've reversed your parameters. The request is the first parameter in a route, the response is the second. As your code stands, you're trying to look for the parameters on the response object, which don't exist.